# IOError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out plistlib.readPlist

Tags: python, plist, plistlib

Sometimes I receive an `IOError` when trying to read a plist file on a network share. The file exists and is never absent from the location in question.

```
tests_info = plistlib.readPlist(network_repo_path + PLIST_PATH)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/.../python2.7/plistlib.py", 
line 75, in readPlist 
pathOrFile = open(pathOrFile)
IOError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out: '/...<nfs share>/Tests.plist'
```

Comment: check if your development environment has permission to access shared location

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it clearly is an error outside of the scope of programming. It relates to an OS, network or server problem.

Comment: I would say that being able to recover from a network access problem, e.g. a time  out or to cope with setting new time outs was potentially a programming issue.

Comment: @guzzli Welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask a question, please use Markdown to format it properly.